# How to dive into data science quickly?

Tags: beginner

I'm new here - I hope this kind of question is legit.

I have a background in mathematics - my field is probability theory, where I am quite strong (top 2% of University).

I have little experience in programming but I guess I get things done once I know what is out there (i.e. what program languages can do for me). 
I want to learn more about data science and dive into the field particular when it comes to programming. I'd also like to get going on manageable yet interesting data science related tasks (building some "usefull" statistics skill might be desirable, too).

I know kaggle.com are there other places I could look into?
Any projects I might take on?

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to both machine learning and programming, try taking a look at this guy's tutorials: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/. I've been using them for a while, and I think they're great because of how visual, hands-on, and practical they are. For example, he has facial recognition and handwriting recognition lessons. I'm using what I learned in his tutorials to build a self driving remote control car (similar to this: https://zhengludwig.wordpress.com/projects/self-driving-rc-car/).

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the following 2 sites as really good starting points:

http://www.becomingadatascientist.com - Interviews, resources, challenges & forums

http://datasciencemasters.org - web resources for self-edification